# Group list with Stream

Tags: java

I have list as below

```
List<Status> deviceStatus = Arrays.asList(
                new Status("ON",  10), // Start
                new Status("ON",  25),
                new Status("OFF", 40), // End
                new Status("ON",  10), // Start
                new Status("OFF", 20), // End
                new Status("ON",  10), // Start
                new Status("ON",  20),
                new Status("ON",  32),
                new Status("ON",  44),
                new Status("OFF", 54)  //End
        );
```

I want to group Start -- End (can skip intermediate Starts) and calculate the difference values. Output which Im expecting is 40 - 10, 20 - 10, 54 - 10. List size will be moderate or high like (2500 - 4000) Im trying to achieve it using Stream() is it possible or I should use foreach loop to calculate it?

Comment: Use what you find the easiest to achieve your goal. Streams are not a good fit.

Comment: I guess you cannot achieve this purely with streams. Since you need to access past data points, you might need to use a HashMap as well.

Comment: @SajithDilshan I really don't see how a HashMap would help doing that.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought, he could use the HashMap to store the immediate past data (can be retrieved in O(n) ) to calculate the difference.

Comment: All he needs is a list of differences, and the current ON status to associate with then next OFF status. A Map is a key/value store. There is no key/value here. Anyway, the algorithm is fairly simple, and the OP should try something on his own.

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> listUtilization =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int statusValue = 0;
        for (Status status : deviceStatus) {
            if (statusValue == 0 && status.getStatus().equals("ON")) {
                statusValue = status.getStatusValue();
            } else if (status.getStatus().equals("OFF")) {
                listUtilization.add(status.getStatusValue() - statusValue);
                statusValue = 0; // Reset status value
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not to use the stream. Streams are designed to provide an ability to apply a finite sequence of operations to the source of elements in a functional style, but not to store elements.

This is normal operation can be performed using looping.

Answer (score -1):

I would say you should use not a list but a TreeMap, and get sublist of it. This is much faster.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Status> statustMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Status>();
    statustMap.put(10, new Status("ON",  10));
    statustMap.put(25, new Status("ON",  25));
    statustMap.put(40, new Status("OFF",  45));
    statustMap.put(10, new Status("ON",  10));
    statustMap.put(20, new Status("OFF",  20));

    find(statustMap, 40, 10);

}

static SortedMap<Integer, Status> find(TreeMap<Integer, Status> statustMap, Integer start, Integer end){
    return statustMap.subMap(start, end);
}
```